# SQL Server optimize SQL request and indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I need to optimize a bunch of SQL requests at work and I can't figure out how to do this for this first (:/) request.

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    call_list.*
FROM
    call_list
LEFT JOIN
    call_lock ON call_lock.call_list_id = call_list.pkid 
              AND call_lock.tenant_id = call_list.tenant_id
WHERE
    call_list.campaign_id IN (SELECT * FROM @listOfCampaigns)
    AND call_list.tenant_id = @tenant_id
    -- filter valid call-backs regarding the date&time
    AND call_list.next_call_dt < @next_call_dt
    -- Agent dated call type
    AND call_list.call_type_id = @call_type_id
    AND call_list.next_agent_id = @next_agent_id
    -- verify a lock is not already set.
    AND call_lock.pkid IS NULL
ORDER BY
    call_list.next_call_priority DESC, call_list.next_call_dt ASC;
```

I've already added an index on the `ORDER BY` columns.

Execution plan shows this:

[image]

More specifically on key lookup (90%)

[image]

I've tried adding the following index, but the execution plan remains the same.

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_call_list_PROC_CALL_LIST_SELECT_AGENT_DATED
ON call_list (call_type_id, next_agent_id);
```

I think I miss something here but I don't know what exactly. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I managed to change execution plan, It was a mistake to create a brand new index, cause it was using the index from ORDER BY columns, in which I've included all columns(...) as suggested, and here is the new execution plan

[image]

Not sure if it is better though ^^'
Here is the description of `@listOfCampaigns` table structure

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Thanks for all your remarks.
I've added a primary key to `@myListOfInt` user-defined table type, and made a `JOIN` with `@listOfCampaigns` and `call_list`. there are only `index scan` or `index seek` in the execution plan. Is `scan` a bad thing ?

[image]

Comment: The plan shows that the index isn't covering; it does a key lookup. The index definition you've provided doesn't `INCLUDE` any columns, so would force the data engine to do a key lookup for any columns you reference in the table that aren't part of the ordering columns. As you use a `SELECT *` that means you want "all" the columns from the table, so for the `INDEX` to be useful you'd need to `INCLUDE` *all* the other columns. Do you really need to return all the columns?

Comment: @ThomA That's a very good question ! I'm not the author of all these requests and I'm discovering the code ... Are you suggesting I should use the INCLUDE clause for index creation and add all the columns from call_list ?

Comment: If you *really* need all the columns then quite possibly; I would personally be questioning if all of them are needed first before I start adding them all to an index's definition. I'd also replace that `*` with an explicit list.

Comment: I've just asked and unfortunately yes they are ... Thanks for the tips !

Comment: it looks like it processes under 1000 rows, do you really need to optimize that?

Comment: @siggermannen It's only a test database, we are not yet in production. But these queries are meant to be called 50 times per second. with only 50000 rows in call_list, we barely get to 10

Comment: @ThomA I've tried using the index INCLUDE clause but the execution plan does not change. I've also tried with an index with all WHERE columns, same result.

Comment: The key lookup happens in part because the server can't use the TVP contents for optimization so it assumes they're a lot, and performs a scan *after* joining the "few" rows it knows about. What's the definition of `@listOfCampaigns` ? Does it have a PK? Even if it does though, there are no statistics so the optimizer can't know how many items are in there

Comment: `call_list.campaign_id IN (SELECT * FROM @listOfCampaigns)` is essentially an INNER JOIN, and that's how it's treated in the execution plan. You could move that in the JOIN clause, eg `call_list INNER JOIN @listOfCampaigns c on call_list.campaign_id=c.Id LEFT JOIN ...`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It sounds like `@listOfCampaign` is a user-defined table type used to provide an array of int to the stored procedure ... and there is no key to it, see my edit

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree with you, there should be a `JOIN` here is that possible with user-defined table types ? Let me try it !

Comment: It's still a *table* type, that's why you can use it in `FROM`. Try making `item` a key at the very least to tell the optimizer it *can* use that column.

Comment: If `@listOfCampaigns.id` is indexed, then replace `call_list.campaign_id IN (SELECT * FROM @listOfCampaigns)` by `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @listOfCampaigns where id = call_list.campaign_id)`.

Comment: @TheImpaler I've used a `JOIN`. However, I will benchmark both solutions with a stress test